# populate a select box in angular js which vale is coming from the get request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a field which is defined as select. I want to populate the drop-down automatically as per the get request but it should also be available to be changed by the user. Following is what I have tried:

```
 $http.get('actual.json').then(function(response) {
             $scope.myBat = response.data;
             $scope.myPayment=$scope.myBat.paymentInterfaceList;
             console.log($scope.myPayment);
       }
```

I have a key-value pair with data `payMent.paymentChannel` the values for payment channel will be `$scope.paychannel = ["WEB","CCD","CSR","CTX","PPD","TEL"];` 
now in html I am not able to get the dropdowns nor is the data being populated my html element is like this :

this td tag is inside a root tr which is as follows `<tr ng-repeat="payMent in myPayment | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchPayment | filter:searchGlobal">`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add a Plunkr or Fiddle, it will be easy for others to check this

Comment: Are you trying to display a list of options in the select ? if so, use ng-repeart

`<label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>`

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/XIBPpfDkxJtTFkVENZA0

Comment: Plunker is working fine.